# How to get current location through Android GPS using Runnables and searching TimeOut?

Tags: android, timer, runnable, locationmanager, locationlistener

I'm trying to develop some solution to get my current location using Android's GPS. However, the search is limited to a timeout and also when search locations begins there is a Dialog which allows user to cancel the search.

To do this, I'm thinking to use a runnable. Following there is the code responsible to the timer (I'm using it in a state machine with switch-case).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddPandlet.this);

                    progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getString(R.string.addpandlet_cancelsearch),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //CANCEL OBTAINING GPS
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                    progressDialog.show();
                    scanLocation();

                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                }
                            });
                            status = Status.FINISH;
                            updateStateMachine();
                        }
                    }, SCAN_PERIOD_GPS);
```

On the LocationListener I'm doing this:

```
LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);

        longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
        latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};
```

Besides, I can't get the gps coordinates because GPS is always listening, and don't stopped when timer ends.

Someone can give me some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove,

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
    latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
```

and try this one

```
    longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
    latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();    
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
locationManager = null;
```